# Re-cloning a mercurial repository without generaldelta

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to do a `hg clone` on an Internet facing machine for later use on an offline build machine. Unfortunately mercurial is 3.9.1 on the Internet machine, but 1.4 on the offline machine.

I get the error `abort: requirement 'generaldelta' not supported!` and also `abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!`

I found this is becuase generaldelta feature was added in 1.9, and dotencode in 1.7. I've used instructions from the [MissingRequirement wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement) to downgrade this repo using the following.

```
hg clone -U --config format.generaldelta=0 --config format.dotencode=0 --pull /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

However the new repo at `/tmp/bar` still uses `generaldelta`, although `dotencode` require has gone. i.e.

```
cat /tmp/bar/.hg/requires 

fncache
generaldelta  <=== still there
revlogv1
store

store
```

How can I rewrite the repo with both generaldelta and dotencode disabled?

Comment: If possible you *really* want to upgrade mercurial from 1.9. That is a very old version and since then an enormous number of bugs have been fixed and performance improvements applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config option should have been `format.usegeneraldelta` not `format.generaldelta`. i.e.

```
hg clone -U --config format.usegeneraldelta=0 --config format.dotencode=0 --pull /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

Note the config. options are all `config.use<feature-name>` apart from `config.dotencode` see [Mercurial format options](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#format). Beware as there is not any error checking either.