# Convert repository to older version (without sparse revlog)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Our team is using Mercurial for version control, with the central repository located on a shared network drive (i.e. we are not using a server). Our company restricts what we can install on our computers, and everyone had Hg version 4.6. One of the team members used admin rights he has to install the latest TortoiseHg (4.9). It seemingly resulted in the central repository to be converted to the newest version. Now another team member, with the old Mercurial, cannot pull from the central repository. It says

> repository requires features unknown to this Mercurial: sparserevlog

I read a bit about it, and it seems that this feature is not critical for us. Would it be possible to revert the central repository to the version without sparse revlog?

Comment: Curious, the format config options docs do NOT include an entry for the latest format "sparse-revlog" (https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#format)  which are all listed here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement#Repository_formats. This is unfortunate, because otherwise that could be part of a solution based on the "Downgrade your repository with a new client" section on the second link where you would disable the latest format. Maybe its worth a try anyway

Comment: I did just add an answer, but for another approach.  I commented on the "format" issue because it seems like a gap that HG wouldn't have accounted for your scenario already. Either it could be supported and be a documentation error, or it just isnt possible to do it that way. I'll see if I can formalize this as a potential answer with more detail...

Comment: @DaveInCaz, I just saw your answer and deleted my request for an answer :)

Comment: I don't know if it would be useful, but you could try posting an issue on https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues and see if you get a helpful response. I can't think of it right now but I'm sure there is something like that for the core hg client too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With 4.9, **new** repositories will be created using `sparse-revlog` by default. However **existing repositories are untouched**. They stay in the same format they have been created with.

#### Avoiding the issue at repository creation

To prevent the users who upgraded to create `sparse-revlog` repositories he needs to set the following in his user configuration (`hg config -e`)

```
[format]
sparse-revlog = no
```

Do you have global control of your users configuration?

#### Downgrading existing repositories

If you want to downgrade such newly created repository you do the following:

1. add the following to the repository configuration (`hg config -l`)

```
[format]
sparse-revlog = no
```

2. run `hg debugupgraderepo --run` (with 4.7 or newer)

#### Upgrading existing repositories

If you want to upgrade existing created repository, the process is similar:

1. add the following to the repository configuration (`hg config -l`)

```
[format]
sparse-revlog = yes
```

2. run `hg debugupgraderepo --run` (with 4.7 or newer)

---

Note: the page https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#format is outdated. The website for mercurial have been `https://www.mercurial-scm.org/` for a couple of years.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it should be possible to instruct hg during a clone operation NOT to use a specific, newer repo format.

There are specific configuration options for this, as [shown in the docs](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#format):

> Config option: `format`
>
> ```
> usegeneraldelta
> ```
>
> Enable or disable the "generaldelta" repository format ...  Enabled by
> default.
>
> ```
> dotencode
> ```
>
> Enable or disable the "dotencode" repository format ...  Enabled by
> default.
>
> ```
> usefncache
> ```
>
> Enable or disable the "fncache" repository format ... Enabled by
> default.
>
> ```
> usestore
> ```
>
> Enable or disable the "store" repository format ... Enabled by
> default.

**However** for some reason there is no option listed corresponding to the newest repo format which as noted in the question is "sparse-revlog" ([documented here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement#Repository_formats)).

But that seems to be *just a documentation oversight*, so [similar to the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689516/3195477), you should be able to re-clone using a command similar to this:

```
hg clone --config format.sparse-revlog=no  <source> <dest>
```

This will require hg to NOT utilize that format, which means the older prior format should be what you get and will be compatible with your local hg clients.

Added info/explanation from a comment by Juan: this will work if (a) your clone source & destination are not on the same filesystem *or* (b) you add `--pull`.

(By default Mercurial will try to create hard links for speed & space savings. Avoiding hard links by cloning to different filesystems or different hosts altogether or by forcing the clone to not use hard links on the same filesystem by using `--pull` will allow the new repo to be created without sparse-revlog.)

I guess you would have to do this to replace every existing clone that has been pulled since the central repo was accidentally upgraded. I would plan that work carefully, to make sure no local changes are lost. You could to a local pull using the same config option to transfer commits from the old to new repos.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `hg clone --config format.usesparserevlog=0  <source> <dest>` actually downgrade anything. At least my old-Hg-user colleague still gets the same error message.

Comment: @texnic that's too bad... Maybe it really isn't supported for some reason? Or could be a different keyword? I won't have a chance to look at the hg source for a while but that would be authoritative...

Comment: Not sure. The method from Pierre-Yves David's answer worked. Set settings, then run `hg debugupgraderepo --run`.

Comment: 'hg clone --config format.sparse-revlog=no' will work if (a) your clone src & dest are not on the same filesystem or (b) you add '--pull'.  By default mercurial will try to create hard links for speed & space savings.  Avoiding hard links (by cloning to different filesystems or different hosts altogether or forcing the clone to not use hard links on the same filesystem by using --pull) will allow the new repo to be created without sparse-revlog.  @StayOnTarget, you can edit your answer to spell 'sparse-revlog' right and to add the information in this comment.

Comment: @Juan thanks for the info, I've made some updates!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach which is kind of ugly (understatement) but might work as a fix, since you only have to do it once...

This approach takes advantage of the fact that an HTTP-served HG instance can apparently interoperate between any internal repo versions.

According to docs [Missing Requirement](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement) section *Downgrade your repository over the network*:

> Because all versions of Mercurial can interoperate over the network,
>   an old client can simply pull from a repository served by a new
>   client:
>
> ```
> # run this on the new client
> $ hg serve
> listening at http://hostname:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
>
> # run this on the old client
> $ hg clone http://hostname:8000/ downgraded-repo
> ```

Since you are not using `hg serve` already this obviously won't work for you automatically. But you might be able to use it temporarily. Something like this:

1. Setup a temporary `hg serve` running on some PC. (Ideally, IT restrictions won't prevent this.) It should serve your central repo.
2. Identify all clones of the repo which need to be fixed. (Maybe cull any which aren't needed to save work here.) These should only need to be ones modified (pushed/pulled) by a THG 4.9 client.
3. Backup work. Ideally, commit and push everything possible first to reduce the later step which restores any backed-up files.
4. Following the example above, re-clone from the temporary `hg serve` PC to new local clones in all instances where they are needed.
5. Restore any backed-up work to the new clones (this is the worst part and could be really painful). I think this has to be done manually; maybe there is a clever diff/patch approach which would be easier.
6. Shut down the temp `hg serve` instance

Be cautious that the problem could eventually re-propagate outwards. i.e., if even one repo is overlooked and later is used to push to the central repo, the problem will repeat itself.

Alternative / variation - you could run `hg serve` on each & every developer's PC that had used THG 4.9, and have them each independently re-clone from localhost. This might get around any IT limitations, if absolutely necessary. (But if you don't have IT limitations, it doesn't really matter where hg serve itself is running).

---

If you have a very large # of affected devs / clones, I am not sure this approach is best. For one thing, if you were able to involve your IT people to upgrade everyone to the newest hg version, it could be a much easier fix overall.

Comment: I cannot have any computer serve hg ot another computer. So I am trying the conversion method. When I am in the repository directory, I run `hg --config format.sparse-revlog=False clone . ..\hg-old`. It does clone but the "requires" file in the result still contains "sparserevlog" (so I assume the old hg will not work with it). Replacing `False` with `false` and `0` don't help either. Any idea?

Comment: Note that you might be able to hg serve just to localhost. worth a shot anyway.

Comment: If the config option does exist, its possible your syntax isn't quite right, that's all I can think of to suggest. You could look in the hg source code to try and find an undocumented option.

Comment: "Setup a temporary hg serve running on some PC" - no, not on *some*, but only on PC with 4.9 repository. And clone by old client to new "downgraded" repo

Comment: @LazyBadger thanks you're right about only the 4.9 cases, I've edited to clarify that. But hg serve really could run on any PC as long as it is serving the correct repo. i.e., it can serve a repo which lives on the file server, it doesn't need to run on the same server.

Comment: This worked for me: `hg clone --config format.sparse-revlog=no <url> <dir>`